# A pdf field became mandatory is there way to clean it

Tags: pdf, forms, data-validation

I downloaded a governmental pdf form and accidentally filled an irrelevant field. Now the filed field became mandatory, and pdf does not pass validation (it has a special 'validate' button).

Obviously I can try to fill it again, but there some many pages to type.
Is there a way to clear the field without breaching document integrity?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to clean that field, yet I exported field data into xml using Foxit and then imported them into the new document. Note that a few field where lost, and , worst, governmental signatures became invalided. So this solution is not so good for me.